# Android - ImageViews have a margin of 0

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I have a FrameLayout inside of a LinearLayout and i am trying to add ImageViews to the FrameLayout on 3 different positions, but they only appear in the top left corner. What did I do wrong?

Here's some code:

```
    obstacles.add(new Obstacle(this, 0, (int) ((scale * 570) / 4), scale));
    layout.addView(obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).view);
    obstacles.add(new Obstacle(this, 0, (int) ((scale * 570) / 2), scale));
    layout.addView(obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).view);
    obstacles.add(new Obstacle(this, 0, (int) ((scale * 570) / 1.3f), scale));
    layout.addView(obstacles.get(obstacles.size() - 1).view);
```

(obstacles is an object list, so i can access the properties of the objects. layout is my FrameLayout of Course.)

Here is also the constructor of the Obstacle class:

```
public Obstacle(Context con, int left, int top, float scale) {
    view = new ImageView(con);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(scale*150), (int)(scale*20));
    params.setMargins(left,top,0,0);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    view.setMaxWidth(view.getLayoutParams().width);
    view.setMaxHeight(view.getLayoutParams().height);
}
```

Comment: You are setting the layout params on the ImageView, try setting it on the LinearLayout. If this works, I will post the answer for you with a good link from Google when I find it again

Comment: I figured it out: i have to use FrameLayout.LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams ind the Obstacle's constructor.

Comment: what did you do? edit: ah, I skimmed over the fact that you added it to the FrameLayout and not the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

[Layouts, Attributes, and you (Android Development Patterns S2 Ep 5)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akP6n9VWHSI)

You should definitely watch this video regardless if you figured out the problem or not.

This is the video you need to watch to understand the issue at hand. The reason you had this issue, is that the layout params are set on the direct PARENT layout, not on the view itself!!

Since the FrameLayout is what is holding the ImageView, you need to be setting the FrameLayout's LayoutParams!